# How to find the snmp enabled device Model Number with SNMP

Tags: snmp

is there a generic OID(s) so that i can get it's Model Number. 
for devices like Cisco, Juniper, Alcatel etc...

For example for sonicWall Router
enterprises.8741.2.1.1.1.0 = snwlSysModel = "TZ 100"

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, no.  There are a few objects to help you get a clue but nothing that lists versions outright.  This is the best one to start with:

```
SNMPv2-MIB::sysObjectID
sysObjectID OBJECT-TYPE
  -- FROM       SNMPv2-MIB, RFC1213-MIB
  SYNTAX        OBJECT IDENTIFIER
  MAX-ACCESS    read-only
  STATUS        current
  DESCRIPTION   "The vendor's authoritative identification of the
            network management subsystem contained in the entity.
            This value is allocated within the SMI enterprises
            subtree (1.3.6.1.4.1) and provides an easy and
            unambiguous means for determining `what kind of box' is
            being managed.  For example, if vendor `Flintstones,
            Inc.' was assigned the subtree 1.3.6.1.4.1.424242,
            it could assign the identifier 1.3.6.1.4.1.424242.1.1
            to its `Fred Router'."
::= { iso(1) org(3) dod(6) internet(1) mgmt(2) mib-2(1) system(1) 2 }
```

followed by looking through the HOST-RESOURCES-MIB and, if supported, the ENTITY-MIB.

Comment: What about  `1.3.6.1.2.1.1`?

Answer (score 0):

```
entPhysicalIndex entPhysicalIndex   1.3.6.1.2.1.47.1.1.1.1.1    OBJECT-TYPE
entPhysicalSoftwareRev entPhysicalSoftwareRev   1.3.6.1.2.1.47.1.1.1.1.10   OBJECT-TYPE
entPhysicalSerialNum entPhysicalSerialNum   1.3.6.1.2.1.47.1.1.1.1.11   OBJECT-TYPE
entPhysicalMfgName entPhysicalMfgName   1.3.6.1.2.1.47.1.1.1.1.12   OBJECT-TYPE
entPhysicalModelName entPhysicalModelName   1.3.6.1.2.1.47.1.1.1.1.13   OBJECT-TYPE
entPhysicalAlias entPhysicalAlias   1.3.6.1.2.1.47.1.1.1.1.14   OBJECT-TYPE
entPhysicalAssetID entPhysicalAssetID   1.3.6.1.2.1.47.1.1.1.1.15   OBJECT-TYPE
entPhysicalIsFRU entPhysicalIsFRU   1.3.6.1.2.1.47.1.1.1.1.16   OBJECT-TYPE
entPhysicalDescr entPhysicalDescr   1.3.6.1.2.1.47.1.1.1.1.2    OBJECT-TYPE
entPhysicalVendorType entPhysicalVendorType 1.3.6.1.2.1.47.1.1.1.1.3    OBJECT-TYPE
entPhysicalContainedIn entPhysicalContainedIn   1.3.6.1.2.1.47.1.1.1.1.4    OBJECT-TYPE
entPhysicalClass entPhysicalClass   1.3.6.1.2.1.47.1.1.1.1.5    OBJECT-TYPE
entPhysicalParentRelPos entPhysicalParentRelPos 1.3.6.1.2.1.47.1.1.1.1.6    OBJECT-TYPE
entPhysicalName entPhysicalName 1.3.6.1.2.1.47.1.1.1.1.7    OBJECT-TYPE
entPhysicalHardwareRev entPhysicalHardwareRev   1.3.6.1.2.1.47.1.1.1.1.8    OBJECT-TYPE
entPhysicalFirmwareRev entPhysicalFirmwareRev   1.3.6.1.2.1.47.1.1.1.1.9    OBJECT-TYPE
```